# Proof Intersection Include Zero

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove that: In $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$: $\forall X \exists Y((X \cap Y = \emptyset) \wedge (x \cup Y = \mathbb{N}))$.

My answer: 
Suppose $X = \{1\}$. But for $X\cap Y = \emptyset$, we need $\emptyset \in X \wedge \emptyset \in Y$, by definition. However, since $X = \{1\}$, we know $\emptyset \notin X$. Therefore, we have proven that the statement is false.

However, I think this may be wrong because $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set, so the intersection between any two given sets must contain $\emptyset$?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: $\emptyset$ is *not* the same as $0$. $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ means that no element lies in both $X$ and $Y$, i.e. they are disjoint. $\emptyset$ is the empty set. Moreover, $X\cap Y=0$ is nonsensical, since the left-hand side is a set, and the right-handside is a number. $X\cap Y=\{0\}$ would make sense, but is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: sorry I meant the empty set instead of zero, sorry!

Comment: @Milten: actually $\emptyset = 0$ under the standard representation of numbers in set theory. However you are quite right about the meaning of $X \cap Y = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $X = \{1\}$, take $Y = \{y : \Bbb{N} \mid y \neq 1\} = \{0, 2, 3, 4, \ldots\}$. Then $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $X \cup Y = \Bbb{N}$. Given an arbitrary $X$, what could you write for $\Phi(y)$ in $Y = \{y : \Bbb{N} \mid \Phi(y)\}$ to ensure that$ X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $X \cup Y = \Bbb{N}$?

Comment: Thank you so much!